# JavaFX Zoom and Pan Group of Shapes - Unable to accurately centre zoom on mouse position

Tags: javafx, zooming, mouse, shapes, group

I'm trying to implement zoom/pane/rotate to a group of shapes. It's working but I’m unable to accurately centre the zoom action on mouse pointer position. It gets worse when zoom in larger and when the mouse position is further away from the group centre.

He is an example of code with zoom/pan/rotate implementation. Zoom is performed with scroll event, pan with drag event, rotation with secondary mouse click and reset to extents with middle mouse click. Also added an animation to show mouse position when scrolling action is started.

I don’t know what else to do.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private StackPane backPane;
    private Group group;

    private Rotate rotate;
    private Translate translate;

    private Point2D startPan = new Point2D(0, 0);
    private Point2D orgTranslate = new Point2D(0, 0);
    private final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        stage.setResizable(false);
        backPane = new StackPane();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(backPane, 800, 400));


        backPane.setOnMousePressed( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    //sets the starting conditions for pan
                    startPan = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
                    orgTranslate = new Point2D(group.getTranslateX(), group.getTranslateY());
                }
            }
        });

        backPane.setOnMouseDragged( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    //executes pan
                    group.setTranslateX(orgTranslate.getX() + event.getSceneX() - startPan.getX());
                    group.setTranslateY(orgTranslate.getY() + event.getSceneY() - startPan.getY());
                }
            }
        } );

        backPane.setOnMouseClicked( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE) {
                    //resets scale of group to full screen
                    resetScale();
                } else if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                    double angle = rotate.getAngle();
                    angle = angle + 45;
                    if (angle >= 360) angle = angle - 360;

                    Point2D groupCenter = new Point2D(0, 0);
                    try {
                        groupCenter = group.getLocalToParentTransform().inverseTransform( backPane.getWidth()/2, backPane.getHeight()/2 );
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                    rotate.setAngle(angle);
                    rotate.setPivotX(groupCenter.getX());
                    rotate.setPivotY(groupCenter.getY());

                    Point2D newGroupCenter = group.getLocalToParentTransform().transform( groupCenter );
                    group.setTranslateX( group.getTranslateX() + backPane.getWidth()/2 - newGroupCenter.getX() );
                    group.setTranslateY( group.getTranslateY() + backPane.getHeight()/2 - newGroupCenter.getY());


                }
            }
        } );

        backPane.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {

                if (event.getDeltaY() == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                //applies scale to group using the mouse pointer position as center
                double scaleFactor =
                        (event.getDeltaY() > 0)
                                ? SCALE_DELTA
                                : 1/SCALE_DELTA;

                scrollAction(event);

                //sets new scale
                group.setScaleX( group.getScaleX() * scaleFactor );
                group.setScaleY( group.getScaleY() * scaleFactor );

                //calculates the distance of the mouse pointer to the center of the group
                double rX = event.getX() - backPane.getWidth()/2 - group.getTranslateX();
                double rY = event.getY() - backPane.getHeight()/2 - group.getTranslateX();
                double modR = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( rX, 2 ) + Math.pow(rY, 2) );
                double angR = Math.atan2( rY, rX );

                //required offset to recenter the group in mouse pointer position
                double dx = modR * (scaleFactor-1) * Math.cos( angR );
                double dy = modR * (scaleFactor-1) * Math.sin( angR );

                group.setTranslateX( group.getTranslateX() - dx );
                group.setTranslateY( group.getTranslateY() - dy );


            }
        });

        generateGraphicItems();

        rotate = new Rotate( 0, Rotate.Z_AXIS );
        translate = new Translate( 0, 0 );
        group.getTransforms().add(rotate);

        drawGroup();

        stage.show();

    }

    private void scrollAction(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {

        //displays animation at the point of scroll
        Point2D mouseP = new Point2D(0,0);

        try {
            mouseP = group.getLocalToParentTransform().inverseTransform(scrollEvent.getX(), scrollEvent.getY());
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        Circle centre = new Circle(mouseP.getX(), mouseP.getY(), 0.01);
        centre.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        centre.setStrokeWidth(0.01);
        centre.setFill(null);
        group.getChildren().add(centre);

        final double step = 0.2;
        final int nCycles = 6;
        final Timeline idlestage = new Timeline( new KeyFrame( Duration.millis( 100 ), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if (centre.getOpacity() >= step) {
                    centre.setOpacity( centre.getOpacity() - step );
                } else {
                    group.getChildren().remove( centre );
                }
            }
        } ) );

        idlestage.setCycleCount( nCycles );
        idlestage.play();

    }

    public void generateGraphicItems() {

        //creates graphical elements
        group = new Group();

        Circle circle = new Circle(0,0, 1.2);
        circle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        circle.setStroke(Color.GOLD);
        circle.setStrokeWidth(0.03);
        circle.setOpacity(0.5);

        group.getChildren().add( circle );

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(-1, -1, 2, 2);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.DARKBLUE);
        rectangle.setStrokeWidth(0.03);
        rectangle.setOpacity(0.5);

        group.getChildren().add( rectangle );


        //aditional elements (circles) to show group boundries and center of the group
        Circle cLL = new Circle(group.getLayoutBounds().getMinX(), group.getLayoutBounds().getMinY(), 0.02);
        cLL.setFill(Color.RED);
        Circle cUL = new Circle(group.getLayoutBounds().getMaxX(), group.getLayoutBounds().getMinY(), 0.02);
        cUL.setFill(Color.RED);
        Circle cLR = new Circle(group.getLayoutBounds().getMinX(), group.getLayoutBounds().getMaxY(), 0.02);
        cLR.setFill(Color.RED);
        Circle cUR = new Circle(group.getLayoutBounds().getMaxX(), group.getLayoutBounds().getMaxY(), 0.02);
        cUR.setFill(Color.RED);
        Circle cC = new Circle((group.getLayoutBounds().getMaxX() + group.getLayoutBounds().getMinX()) / 2,
                (group.getLayoutBounds().getMaxY() + group.getLayoutBounds().getMinY()) / 2, 0.02);
        cC.setFill(Color.RED);

        group.getChildren().addAll( cLL,cUL,cLR,cUR, cC );


    }

    public void drawGroup() {

        group.setAutoSizeChildren( true );
        backPane.getChildren().add( group );

        resetScale();

    }

    public void resetScale() {

        //resets group scale to full screen
        double vScale = backPane.getHeight()/(group.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());
        double hScale = backPane.getWidth()/(group.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
        double scale = Math.min( vScale, hScale );
        group.setScaleX( scale );
        group.setScaleY( scale );

        group.setTranslateX( 0 );
        group.setTranslateY( 0 );

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you using Point class ?

Comment: `Point`  comes from `javafx.scene.effect.Light.Point;`  you need Point2d , perhaps

Comment: Don't really know why I used `Point` instead of `Point2D`. Changed `Point` to `Point2D` but the behaviour is still the same. Any other suggestions?